# How to remove empty directories after tar?

Tags: shell, sed, tar

I'm making a build file, and I need your help please.

1. Current dirs/files are located as the followings

   `/home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/file1 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/file2 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/eee/file3 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/fff/file4 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/file5 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/file6 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/iii/file7 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/file8 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/file9`
2. I want to get target files from list.txt and bind into an archive file. 
   **cat list.txt**

   `/aaa/ 
   /aaa/bbb/ 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/ 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/file4 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/ 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/file5 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/ 
   /aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/file6 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/ 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/file7 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/ 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/file8 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/ 
   /aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/file9`
3. I tried like below.

   `sed -e '\@/$@ d' -e 's@^/@@' list.txt > list2.txt
   tar -cz -f list.tar.gz -C /home/myhome -T list2.txt --remove-files --same-permissions`
4. And the reamining dirs/files were following. 
   (The empty dirs were not removed.)

   `/home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/file1 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/file2 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/eee/file3 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/ 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/ 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/ 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/`
5. But, this is what I expected.

   `/home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/file1 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/ddd/file2 
   /home/myhome/aaa/bbb/ccc/eee/file3`

Could you help me please ?

==================== 
reply to the comments

Now I tried to modify list2.txt (by using vim not script) as the following. 
**cat list2.txt**
    
    `aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/file9 
    aaa/bbb/iii/kkk/ 
    aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/file8 
    aaa/bbb/iii/jjj/ 
    aaa/bbb/iii/file7 
    aaa/bbb/iii/
    aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/file6 
    aaa/bbb/fff/hhh/ 
    aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/file5 
    aaa/bbb/fff/ggg/ 
    aaa/bbb/fff/file4 
    aaa/bbb/fff/`

This is what I want! thank you, Etan.

But I don't know how to remove **aaa**, **aaa/bbb** from original **list.txt**. 
In this case, **aaa/bbb** is the common parent directory, but it can be changed to **aaa/bbb/zzz** in some cases.

Comment: The question here is why didn't tar remove the empty `fff/ggg`, `fff/hhh`, etc. directories?

Comment: Thanks! I replied in the body.

Comment: I don't understand the updated question. You want to delete the `/aaa/bbb` directory from disk or from the path in the file?

Comment: from the path in the file. /aaa/bbb and /aaa/bbb/ccc/* should remain in disk.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your sed call:

```
sed -e '\@/$@ d' -e 's/@^/@@' list.txt > list2.txt
```

You were missing the `/` after the `s` in the `-e s...` expression. Without this fix, `list2.txt` will be empty.

Comment: The `@` in that expression is the marker not the `/`. Your version is a syntax error as the final `/` doesn't exist. His version is correct to replace a leading slash with nothing.

Comment: @EtanReisner, it didn't work for me when I tried it out - had to add the `/` in the second `-e`.

Comment: What version of sed are you using? What (error?) do you get if you run `echo /foo/bar | sed -e 's@^/@@'`?

Answer (score 0):

Since your are asking to remove empty folders only (Though I think the `sed` command is strange/wrong, I have no idea about your goal, and thus I can not make changes to your `sed`.  I will just assume your `sed` works fine for your goal), here's a way to do it:

```
xargs -i rmdir {} < flist.txt 2> /dev/null
xargs -i dirname {}  < flist.txt | xargs -i rmdir {} 2> /dev/null
```

The first line regard each line of flist.txt as a directory name and try to remove it when it is empty (fail if it is a file, which is OK).
The second line take each line of flist.txt and get its upper directory name, and try to remove it when it is empty.

Note: This script does not handle spaces in the directory/file names.